# Is there an application that can fake permanent delete

Tags: windows

I'm just thinking about this, is there an application that can fake permanent delete of a file. For example, you press shift+del on the keyboard. And the file is permanently deleted. Is there an application that makes it look like it has been deleted. Or is there an application that can recover these files that are permanently deleted using shift+delete

Comment: Why use Shift+Delete if you don't want to permanently delete it? Unless you desperately need disk space, just delete them normally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"fake delete": move it to some folder of your choice. the normal delete does this by choosing the "trash"-folder.

there are applications which can recover "shift-delete", as long as the bits on the disk are not yet overwritten ('[recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva)') for example

Comment: So why not replace the location of your trash-folder?

Comment: the whole idea is useless (i dont mean yours, ivo). to have an "arbitrary" named folder to "hide" files is just .. either crypt it, set permissions to not allow people to list stuff in your folders or delete it for real. :)

Comment: @akira, you didn't answer fully OP's question. OP wants to change behaviour of `SHIFT-DEL` so for example `SHIFT-DEL` will move a file rather than delete it (by marking it deleted in the file system table)

Comment: @Chris: the "mark as accepted" sign next to my answer tells you how OP thinks of this answer.